# How can I manually set values for `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/thermal_throttle/*`?

Tags: kernel, cpu, system, overheating, sensors

Something seems to be wrong with either my motheboard or battery, because incorrect and static values are being recorded to

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/thermal_throttle/core_throttle_count     
2906

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/thermal_throttle/package_throttle_count 
3483
```

My sensors however do seem to be correct. I'd like to manually set these two values, and see if that solves my throttling issues.

How can I do that?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David 20.04. I'm willing to edit the kernel source and create a custom one if need be, I've just never done it before.